# Destroy file info/session storage for socket.io file upload

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Writing with Express in Node, I'm trying to either only store the upload info within an active session, or delete the file information after the socket completes. I'm following [this documentation](https://github.com/rico345100/socket.io-file) (destroy method) but error always says the function doesn't exist. I am running the most recent version of Node and have the right version of the package installed too, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Server code:

```
 uploader.on('complete', function(fileInfo) {
    console.log('Upload Complete.');
    console.log(fileInfo);
    util.process(fileInfo.uploadDir, function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
        io.emit('There was an error', error);
        console.log('There was an error');
      } else {
        io.emit('upload completed', data);
      };
    });
    uploader.destroy(fileInfo, function(fileInfo) {
      console.log('destroyed file');
    });
  });
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? It works up until `uploader.destroy`, which is where I reach the console error. I can't imagine I'd need to define the method if it's built into the package..

I've also tried different variations of using `destroy` and I just end up with the same error.

### Update

I was able to bypass the error - it was a version issue after all. However, now I can't get the destroy event to occur once I emit the completed upload. Same code as before.